# Create and manage nested array

Tags: php, arrays, irc

I've tried for a while to figure out how to get this to work and after a lot of Google and not being able to find a problem similar to mine (maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing?) I decided to ask:

I've got incoming data that shows essentially a binary tree of IRC server UUIDs, that is the server's UUID and its parent's UUID. What I want to do is create an array that's a tree of this, the incoming data is sort of as follows:

```
Parent => Child
none => 01D
01D => 01B
01B => 01F
01B => 8OS
01B => 01k
01K => 01M
```

And I want it to be in an array such as:

```
$tree = array('01D' => array(
                       '01B' => array(
                                '01F' => array(),
                                '8OS' => array(),
                                '01k' => array('01M' => array()));
```

I don't get the data all at once, and it's not in a database, so essentially I need to be able to add branches at will.

The primary reason I want to do it this way is in case one of the server disappears, say "01F" I know which children are its and can go through those. So, how would I loop through the children in that regard? Essentially in an IRC context, dealing with netsplits.

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this, probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense for the incoming data to be in this format:

```
Parent => Child
none => 01D
01D => 01B
01B => 01F
01B => 8OS
01B => 01k
01K => 01M
```

...because the keys are non-unique (ex. `01B`).  You should flip the array so it looks like this:

```
$uuids = array(
    '01D' => NULL,
    '01B' => '01D',
    '01F' => '01B',
    '8OS' => '01B',
    '01K' => '01B',
    '01M' => '01K'
);
```

Finding the children of a failed node is a simple loop and `in_array()` call:

```
$failedNodes = array('01B'); // original failed node

foreach ($uuids as $child => $parent) {
    if (in_array($parent, $failedNodes)) {
        $failedNodes[] = $child;
    }
}

var_dump($failedNodes);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "01B"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "01F"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "8OS"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "01k"
}
```

Comment: My issue also is traversing children of children of children ad infinitum. So would recursively calling a function in some way be best for dealing with that? That is to say, find children of lost node, and go through their children's children?

Comment: @TheRealRoxette:  Yes, that's pretty much a text book use-case for recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Well i usually use references or objects in this case. What i'll show you here is how to use references, a pattern is like a lot.

```
//Initialize your server array
$servers = array();

//Then, each time you get a new server to add, add it to the server list if it doesn't exist
if(!isset($servers[$myname])){
    $servers[$myname] = array(
        'name' => 'data1',
        'prop1' => 'data2',
        'prop2' => 'data3',
        'prop3' => 'data4',
        'prop4' => 'data5',
        'childrens' => array(),
    );
}

//Then add your server to the children of the appropriate server
if(isset($servers[$myparent])){
    $servers[$myparent]['childrens'][] = &$servers[$myname];
}
```

This will create a list of all possible servers and will link each entry to a children of another. This way, if you remove a server, you don't lose the data inside of this children, you only lose the reference.

If you where to foreach the children, you'd get the data you referenced, var_dump, print_r??? They all work fine... unset($servers['thatoneserver']) you still keep all you server data but lose that server and the links to their children.

Et voila...

Comment: Thanks, i'll make a mental note on that

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rebuild the tree. Simply maintain the parent-child relationship. From your *primary reason* you only care about the children anyway.

```
$nodes = array(
  '01D' => array('01B'),
  '01B' => array('01F', '8OS', '01k'),
  // ...
);
```

Then when a node fails, you can easily find the children (`$nodes[$failed]`) and traverse from there.